# '1A' is not accepted in [:alnum:] POSIX Character Class under Oracle regular expresssion

Tags: regex, oracle11g, alphanumeric

Why is '1A' not considered in alphanumeric class?

```
SELECT 'yes'
FROM dual
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('1A', '[:alnum:]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of unescaped `[...]` creates a [*bracket expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). POSIX character classes, like `[:alpha:]`, `[:alnum:]`, can only be declared inside a bracket expression.

> `[:digit:]` is a POSIX character class, used inside a bracket expression like `[x-z[:digit:]]`.

Use the POSIX character class inside  a bracket expression:

```
SELECT 'yes' FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('1A', '[[:alnum:]]')
```

[image]

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/DWXJ59078).

> `('1a', '[:alnum:]')` seems to acceptable.

Note that when you use `'[:alnum:]'`, the regex engine parses it as a regular bracket expression matching any characters/character ranges defined inside the bracket expression. I.e. the `[:alnum:]` regex matches any single char that is either `:`, `a`, `l`, `n`, `u` or `m`. Since your input has `a` (`1a`) the regex engine returns a valid match once it encounters `a` in the input.

Comment: Okay thank you, can you also give the reason why using it should be in other bracket. As  `('1a', '[:alnum:]')` seems to acceptable.